# Como saber quando devo usar cada uma das funções de execução?

Tags: php

Como funciona cada uma das funções do PHP:

1. `pcntl_exec('/caminho/executar');`
2. `exec('/caminho/executar');`
3. `shell_exec('/caminho/executar');`

Existe alguma singularidade entre os 3 exemplos citados acima?

Embora fica claro de que o `exec()` é para executar programa diretamente, o `shell_exec()` também pode executar um programa através de linha de comando, e o `pcntl_exec()` que também executa programa, mas tem algo a ver com processo, o que não entendi direito.

A **documentação do PHP** não me direcionou muito bem para entender essas diferenças: [**pcntl_exec**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php), [**exec**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) e [**shell_exec**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: Cadê o @Bacco quando você precisa dele!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Além desses 3 que você citou ainda existe o `passthru` e o `system` para execução de caminhos.

- `pcntl_exec` Cria um processo separado do processo principal com o comando executado, ainda permite que seja setado argumentos e outras configurações como qual usuário deve executar esse processo(apenas se você tiver como root), ele é desenvolvido para sistemas UNIX e não pode ser usado em webservers, apenas no php executado via command line(CLI). Ela é muito útil se você estiver desenvolvendo uma uma aplicação que precisa gerenciar os espaços de trabalho e a qual usuário delegar o processo. O detalhe é que essa função faz parte da extensão PCNTL: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pcntl.php
- `exec` Apenas retorna a última linha gerada pelo output da execução do programa especificado.
- `shell_exec` Retorna todo o output do comando, quando este terminou de ser executado.
- `system` Executa imediatamente exibindo a saída, é usado para exibir textos.
- `passthru` Também retorna o output imediatamente porém é usado para exibir os dados binários. `passthru` exibe o "raw data" diretamente para o navegador.

Com ambos comandos `exec` e`shell_exec` é possível capturar o output(ou saída), enquanto o `system` e o `passthru` não vai deixar você personalizar e exibir imediatamente a saída.

O `pcntl_exec` fez-se necessário quando precisamos criar um bloco de código que rodasse de forma assincronia à requisição principal, compatível apenas quando o php está rodando em fast-cgi ou php-fpm, no apache_handler não irá funcionar. Ele permite que você faça uma "ramificação" aonde seu código segue 2 caminhos com base em um if, um dentro do processo "filho" e outro no processo "Pai".