# Como fazer Thread de um método da classe

Tags: php, thread

Estou precisando realizar um processo em paralelo utilizando o php, instalei a extensão [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pthreads.php) e observei alguns exemplos mas não vi como eu poderia implementa-lo.

**Classe:**

```
<?php

class Negociacao{
    /*
        Retorna código de rastreio das condições do usuário.
    */
    public function SolicitarOpcoesPagamento($cpfOuCnpj, $telefone, $email, $nrParcelas, $dataPagamento){
        $codigo =  md5($cpfOuCnpj); 
        //ConsultarOpcoesPagamento($codigo); <- aqui dou start na thread
        return $codigo;
    } 

    /*
        Retorna status e array de condições do usuário.
    */
    public function ConsultarOpcoesPagamento($codigo){
        return array("status" => "pendente","opcoes"=> array());
    }

}
```

**Servidor Soap:**

```
<?php

$options = array("uri" => "http://localhost/soap/");

$server = new SoapServer(null, $options);

require_once "negociacao.php";

$server->setObject(new Negociacao());

$server->handle();

?>
```

**Cliente Soap:**

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'uri' => 'http://localhost/soap/server.php',
    'location' => 'http://localhost/soap/server.php'
);

$client = new SoapClient(null, $options);

var_dump($client->solicitarOpcoesPagamento(025111151544));

?>
```

**Objetivo:**

Quando o cliente chamar a função `SolicitarOpcoesPagamento` eu devo retornar um id de rastreamento imediatamente, porém antes de retornar esse id eu preciso executar dentro dessa função em paralelo a função `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento`, que vai ir em outro webservice, montar as opções e inserir no meu banco de dados. Quando o cliente quiser ele vai consultar a função `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento` que já estará com os dados.

Comment: Vc precisa retornar imediatamente ou consultar primeiro?

Comment: Eu preciso retornar o código de rastreamento  e executar a função ConsultarOpcoesPagamento em paralelo

Comment: Nesse caso você precisa criar duas threads e sincronizar as duas correto?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo visualizar a utilização de threads para isso. Unica forma que eu estou conseguindo enxergar é se você chamasse `SolicitarOpcoesPagamento()` e `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento()` separadamente e independente uma da outra. Mas como você disse, isso não ocorre.

Comment: **Relacionado:** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207984/3635, talvez a parte que lhe seja interessante seja aonde falei: **Aonde Thread seria interessante**, ainda sim recomendo que leia tudo para entender alguns detalhes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela recomendação!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não sei se entendi bem seu problema, mas se entendi, acredito que você não precisará criar uma *thread* apenas para isso. O que você pode fazer é entregar a resposta HTTP da solicitação ao cliente e continuar com o seu código. No exemplo abaixo eu adaptei um pouco o seu código apenas para testes.

```php
class Negociacao {

    public function SolicitarOpcoesPagamento($data){
        $codigo =  md5($data); 
        return $codigo;
    } 

    public function ConsultarOpcoesPagamento($codigo){
        file_put_contents(
            "output.json", 
            json_encode(
                array(
                    "status" => "pendente",
                    "opcoes"=> array(
                        "codigo" => $codigo
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Ou seja, o método `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento` criará um código único a partir de um dado qualquer e o método `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento` gerará um JSON básico contendo a informação gerada pelo método anterior. No seu caso, esse método iria trabalhar com o banco de dados, conforme a sua necessidade real. Para finalizar a requisição e enviar a resposta ao cliente, pode fazer algo como:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

ob_start();

$neg = new Negociacao();
$codigo = $neg->SolicitarOpcoesPagamento("Foo");

echo "Seu código de acesso é: ", $codigo;

header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// Seu código continuará aqui...
```

Neste caso, ao abrir a página PHP, o cliente obterá a seguinte mensagem:

```
Seu código de acesso é: 1356c67d7ad1638d816bfb822dd2c25d
```

Mas o código continuará sendo executado. Para simular um processo mais demorado, irei utilizar a função `sleep` e após invocar o método `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento`:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

ob_start();

$neg = new Negociacao();
$codigo = $neg->SolicitarOpcoesPagamento("Foo");

echo "Seu código de acesso é: ", $codigo;

header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// Seu código continuará aqui...

sleep(5);

$neg->ConsultarOpcoesPagamento($codigo);
```

Assim, 5 segundos após você obter a resposta no navegador, o arquivo `output.json` será criado com o conteúdo:

```
{"status":"pendente","opcoes":{"codigo":"1356c67d7ad1638d816bfb822dd2c25d"}}
```

Comment: Desta forma ai da certo, mas ai vem um problema, se eu estiver servindo essa classe usando o SoapServer ele só vai aceitar return $data, se você fizer um echo ele vai emitir "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in"

Comment: Bem que este detalhe poderia estar explícito na pergunta...

Comment: Você esta certo, eu sempre tento criar seguindo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve vou editar para ficar completo, obrigado.

Comment: Com a sua resposta consegui chegar a esta solução: https://gist.github.com/Gabrielr47/23fd7e402ad9e56812f5ec7816d2f40c  acredito que é isso mesmo, só vou aguardar para ver se existe alguma solução melhor senão irei concluir.

Answer (score 6):

Talvez sua pergunta não seja sobre threads em sí, porém esta pergunta será acessada por pessoas que buscam soluções sobre threads em php.

Antes de tudo, é importante entender a definição do que é uma threads:

> Na ciência da computação,Thread é um pequeno programa que trabalha
>   como um subsistema, sendo uma forma de um processo se autodividir em
>   duas ou mais tarefas.

Este é um procedimento bem complexo para se realizar com PHP,  já que paralelismo não é usualmente o foco dos programadores PHP, porém não é impossível de se fazer. E ainda existem várias abordagens, algumas mais simples e seguras outras nem tanto. Veja abaixo alguns métodos para realizar ou simular threads no php.

### Método 1: Criar uma chamada ao seu próprio servidor

A primeira abordagem, mais simples é a definida nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217559/7130 
Porém este método não é uma execução é assíncrona e seria menos performática do que chamar um método diretamente dentro do mesmo processo.

### Método 2:  Cronjobs

Outra abordagem, também bem simples é a do cron ou cronjob, no windows agendador de tarefas.
A técnica consiste em cria uma rotina que é lida de tempos em tempos atrás de alguma "tarefa" que está agendada, você pode armazenar essa lista de tarefas à serem executadas pelo script em um banco de dados ou arquivo com os parâmetros.
Não é muito performática também, porém é mais simples e fácil de implementar, basta que você tenha acesso a um recurso de agendamento de tarefa.

### Método 3:  PHP Process Control ([PCNTL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101827/como-saber-quando-devo-usar-cada-uma-das-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/101839#101839) )

Bom, todos os métodos acima não podem ser executados deforma assíncrona de verdade, separando o processo do php em 2. **Talvez esteja seja a única forma de fazer uma thread de um método de uma classe.**
Precisando criar uma solução que fizesse exatamente isso, aonde fosse possível  inicializar uma rotina/método que ficasse em execução em background enquanto eu já desse o retorno para o usuário e depois apenas verificasse o progresso e o log dessa tarefa.

O resultado foi a elaboração de uma classe abstrata à ser estendida por sub-classes com as tarefas específicas, no exemplo abaixo no link do gist eu faço a exclusão de arquivos em forma assíncrona e gravo logs durante o processo
Veja parte do método abaixo:

```
/**
     * Executa a tarefa com os parâmetros pré-definidos.
     * @param mixed $parameters
     */
    final public function run($parameters) {
        try {
            //Não tenho certeza se há necessidade, 
            //porém essas funções adicionam um controle para que o 
            //processo continue à ser execudado mesmo que o usuário abandone a tela.
            ignore_user_abort(true);
            set_time_limit(0);
            // Inicializo o signal Handler
            pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
            $pid = pcntl_fork(); //Cria um novo processo, se criado com sucesso, o código executado daqui para baixo será executado em outra thread.
            if ($pid == -1) {//Se o retorno for -1 significa que não foi possível.
                throw new \RuntimeException("Could not start a fork process.");
            } else if ($pid) {
                //Se o valor for diferente de zero Significa que ainda está rodando no pai
//                pcntl_waitpid($pid, $exitcode, WNOHANG); // prevents zombie processes
//                 $this->log("Thread Still the same");
                return;
            } else {
                ignore_user_abort();
                $sid = posix_setsid();
                self::$shmId = shm_attach((int) (ftok(self::$file, 'A') . self::$line), self::SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE);
                $this->var_key_fork_pid = $this->alocatesharedMemory($sid, 112105100); //112105100
                shm_put_var(self::$shmId, $this->var_key_status, 'RUNNING');
//                $this->log("SubTask" . $sid);
//                $this->log("SubPid" . $this->var_key_fork_pid);
//                $this->log("Substatus" . $this->var_key_status);
                $this->onPreExecute($parameters);
//                $this->log("SessionDelay: " . session_id());
                try {
                    $result = $this->doInBackground($parameters);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->log("[ErrExec:" . $e->getCode() . "] " . $e->getMessage());
                    $this->cancel($e->getMessage());
                }
                $this->onPostExecute($result);
                //Ao finalizar, emitir o sinal de finalizado e apagar a memória compartilhada alocada.
                if (@shm_has_var(self::$shmId, $this->var_key_fork_pid)) {
                    shm_put_var(self::$shmId, $this->var_key_fork_pid, null);
                    shm_put_var(self::$shmId, $this->var_key_status, 'FINISHED');
                    shm_remove(self::$shmId);
                    gc_collect_cycles();
                    posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $msg = "[Err:" . $e->getCode() . "] " . $e->getMessage(); 
            $this->log($msg);
            self::onError($msg,$e);
        }
    }
```

Explicação:
A separação da thread acontece na linha aonde eu uso a seguinte função:
`$pid = pcntl_fork();` essa função poderá retornar -1 se falhar ao criar a ramificação do processo (fork). O valor diferente de 0 é o bloco que continuará executando no processo principal o outro valor é o id do processo "filho" ou fork, esse bloco será executado num processo completamente separado.
Para fazer a comunicação entre os 2 eu utilizo a memória compartilhada, já que são 2 processos separados e ambos não tem acesso às mesmas variáveis(nem mesmo por $_SESSION).

Sendo assim dentro do seu exemplo poderia ficar algo assim:

```
if($pid == 0){ //Se estiver na thread principal
 SolicitarOpcoesPagamento();
}else if($pid != -1){ //Se tiver no fork
 ConsultarOpcoesPagamento();
}
```

Exemplo Completo: https://gist.github.com/LeonanCarvalho/62c6fe0b62db8a478f502f84c5734c83
Neste meu exemplo você precisaria modelar uma classe para cada tarefa, essas classes devem herdar da classe abstrata e implementa alguns métodos.

Ele consiste em usar as funções do pcntl, que é a extensão oficial do php para controle de processo, principalmente a função [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pcntl-fork.php) para criar uma separação do processo principal.
Também foi necessário utilizar algumas extensões auxiliares como a [POSIX](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.posix.php) e "[Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.sem.php)".

Resultado do exemplo acima:
[image: Exemplo]

Um problema conhecido por mim é que não é possível usar instâncias do PDO em modo singleton entre 2 processos, você precisa no processo ramificado ("fork") destruir a instancias singleton do PDO e então criar uma nova conexão PDO.

Este método está em uso a 1 ano, ele é responsável por fazer importação de arquivos para dentro do sistema, ao invés de ocupar a conexão com o servidor eu apenas recebo os dados e depois processo ele em background no servidor, liberando a conexão do usuário para que ele continue à trabalhar no sistema.

### Método 4:  Pthreads

Embora já exista no php 5.6, recomendo fortmente utilizá-lo apenas no PHP7, ele foi completamente refatorado no PHP7 e está mais seguro de ser utilizado. Isso exigirá uma versão ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) do PHP 7.x instalada, juntamente com o pthreads v3 instalado. Até o momento não encontrei link para baixar essa versão pronta, mas você ainda pode compilá-la https://www.sitepoint.com/install-php-extensions-source/#installing-a-third-party-extension ( Link em inglês).

A documentação oficial é: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Porém os bons exemplos estão aqui: https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/ (link em inglês)

No caso específico da pergunta, não sei se esses 2 últimos método atenderiam, não há como você ter certeza que o `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento` terminará em paralelo com o `ConsultarOpcoesPagamento`, mas ficaria algo assim:

```
class OpcoesPagamento extends Threaded
{
    public $codigo;
    public $opcoes;

    public function Solicitar($cpfOuCnpj, $telefone, $email, $nrParcelas, $dataPagamento)
    {
        /** **/
        $this->codigo = md5($cpfOuCnpj); 
    }

    public function Consultar()
    {
        $this->opcoes = array("status" => "pendente","opcoes"=> array());
    }
}
$OpcoesPagamento = new OpcoesPagamento;


$thread = new class($OpcoesPagamento) extends Thread {
    private $task;

    public function __construct(Threaded $task)
    {
        $this->task = $task;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->task->Solicitar();
        $this->task->Consultar();       
    }
};
$thread->start() && $thread->join();

var_dump($task->codigo);
var_dump($task->opcoes);
```

Outro projeto relevante que possa ser de interesse é este com bastante exemplos: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads, também requere PHP7. Não encontrei versão compatível com linux.

Resumindo, há várias formas de se realizar uma Thread em um método da classe, uns simulando e outros com componentes específicos, asíncronos ou síncronos. Qual você usar deve usar deve estar baseado nos seus requisitos e na sua infra estrutura, já que precisam de um conhecimento um pouco avançado para se implementar alguma dessas técnicas.

Comment: Não use formatação de título para dar ênfase. Também é recomendável por o código significativo na resposta também, não apenas num link referenciado

Comment: Posso por 500 linhas de código na resposta? como vou separar os scripts? Snippet so é possível com js, html e css.

Comment: por isso falei significativo. O quanto é focado na PCNTL, o quanto é bloat?

Comment: Pelo que vi, o foco seria na função `run` e no método abstrato, correto? O resto pode por uma elipse `[...]` para indicar que tem mais coisa por debaixo dos panos

Comment: Olha a resposta do Anderson nessa mesma pergunta, ele se focou em postar o código essencial e deixar os excessos de lado/subentendido, já que não eram necessários

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, farei a edição assim que possível.

Comment: @Everson os métodos onError, onDestroy, onCancelled são "eventos", vc deve implementar o que fazer nesses eventos dentro da classe filha, que é a que faz o processamento.

Comment: Essa resposta visa explorar o tema, "Como fazer thread de um método da classe" em php, dentro do tema abordado, apresentei 4 métodos de execução de paralelismo,a outra pergunta responde algo fora do contexto de thread em php, (devido ao teor específico do problema do autor em que o caso apresentado não é necessário fazer thread).

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho, obrigado pelo excesso, o google me direcionou aqui por causa dele era tudo que eu precisava.