# Como continuar a execução de um script, mesmo depois de enviar os dados ao navegador?

Tags: php, http

Quando fiz a pergunta
[Qual é a solução para processos assíncronos em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207775/qual-%C3%A9-a-solu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-processos-ass%C3%ADncronos-em-php), basicamente o que eu tinha em ente era essa pergunta:

> "Existe alguma forma de concluir uma requisição de um cliente, mas deixar um processo sendo executado no mesmo script que serve a este cliente, como por exemplo, um registro no banco de dados seguido de um envio de um e-mail?

Eu acabei percebendo que pensar na palavra "assíncronismo" talvez não fosse a abordagem mais correta, visto que não quero processo paralelos.

Quando uma requisição é enviada a um script PHP, todo o processamento é feito ali para, ao fim das operações, a resposta ser enviada ao cliente. E o cliente (navegador), por sua vez, fica aguardando o término da execução daquele processo.

A pergunta que fiz anteriormente sobre processos assíncronos já tem várias respostas sobre como "driblar" esse pequeno problema do PHP.

Mas o que eu gostaria de saber é: Existe alguma maneira de, ao se fazer uma requisição a um script PHP, enviar uma resposta ao cliente, porém esse mesmo script continuar sendo executado do lado do servidor, até terminar uma longa operação?

Por exemplo:

```
gravar_dados_no_banco();

// Envia a resposta pro navegador
// Porém ele não precisa mais esperar o término desse script
echo json_encode(['status' => true]);

// Depois da resposta acima
// Faço algumas operações demoradas
// Que não serão "esperadas" pelo navegador

 sleep(3);

 mandar_email_pro_admin();

 atualizar_todos_webservices();
```

Comment: Acho que o q vc pretende fazer não é possível com PHP, usar ajax não te ajuda??

Comment: @FernandoVR é possível sim, eu fiz a pergunta mais no sentido informativo. Se ninguém responder, eu vou responder, para o pessoal aprender esse truque :)

Comment: Ahh ok, pq o modo mais fácil que imaginei de resolver oq  vc precisa, seria em requisições via ajax.  Vc manda um comando para gravar os dados e retornar a resposta do json, e em seguida ja enviar outra pra enviar o Email. Eu a muito tempo ja pensei nessa possibilidade do q vc quer fazer em PHP, mas nunca achei uma solução para isso, ja q o php bloqueia o retorno até o final da execução de todo script.

Comment: @FernandoVR vou te dar uma dica: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response

Comment: Lembro de já ter respondido isso. Verei se consigo achar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217559/5878

Comment: Muito bacana esse método @WallaceMaxters, e a resposta do Anderson, tbm é muito boa. Utilizando `ignore_user_abort(true);` e `set_time_limit(0);` eu até fechei o navegador depois do retorno da tela, e mesmo assim ele continuou executando o script até o fim.
Quando eu tentei no passado, eu queria q ele continuasse exibindo resultados na tela, sem parar o script. Mas esse método tbm é muito bom.

Comment: @FernandoVR sim. Aqui onde trabalho, tem um script que eu preciso registar que uma solicitação foi cancelada, depois que ela é cancelada (registro no banco), eu respondo pro cliente que ele cancelou com sucesso, porém depois dessa resposta, preciso ao mesmo tempo enviar um e-mail para o dono da solicitação e fazer uma requisição no webservice. Isso salvou minha vida!

Comment: Ahh entendi @WallaceMaxters, eu ja fiz algo parecido, mas sempre esperava o script terminar para resultar tudo na tela. Mas realmente dessa forma é ótimo e acaba ganhando bastante velocidade na resposta. Gostei bastante, e agora q também aprendi como se faz, irei utilizar bastante. ^^ Abraços amigo, tenha um ótimo dia.

Comment: @FernandoVR estou testando aqui e o meu está aguardando o término. Mas a intenção não é essa. Eu vou continuar testando aqui, ele tem que terminar a resposta, mas continuar o script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Baseado na resposta do Anderson, não deu certo assim Wallace?

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

gravar_dados_no_banco();

ob_start();

// Envia a resposta pro navegador
// Porém ele não precisa mais esperar o término desse script
echo json_encode(['status' => true]);

header('Connection: close');
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());

ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();

// Depois da resposta acima
// Faço algumas operações demoradas
// Que não serão "esperadas" pelo navegador

sleep(3);

mandar_email_pro_admin();

atualizar_todos_webservices();
?>
```

Pra mim aqui depois do `flush();` ele exibiu o resultado na tela, e mesmo q eu feche o navegador ele continuou executando o resto do script.

Tem q ver então se for o caso, se a suas outras funções mais abaixo, não tenha algo q está impedindo o retorno. 
Pq pelo q eu sei, o php lê primeiro toda a estrutura de código, includes, funções e classes que estão sendo utilizadas para depois começar a execução.

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Ahhh ok q bom q funcionou ^_^

Comment: Fernando, entra no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) aí, fera, kkkkk

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Vi só agora a msg kkk foi mal, to na maior correria aqui com um trampo rsrs, não vai dar pra acompanhar o chat por enquanto rsrs, mas sempre q puder prometo entrar lá rsrs ^^ Abraços amigo

Answer (score 10):

## Como fazer isso no PHP com configurações comuns?

Eu fiz um teste no framework Laravel e consegui o resultado esperado.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $response = Response::json([
        'process' => true
    ]);

    return Response::withShutdownTask($response, function () {
        minha_tarefa_demorada();
    });

});


Response::macro('withShutdownTask', function ($response, callable $callback) {

    $response->header('Connection', 'Close');
    $response->header('Content-Encoding', 'none');
    $response->header('Content-Length', mb_strlen($response->getContent()));

    register_shutdown_function(static function () use ($callback) {
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
        @ob_flush();
        sleep(3);
        $callback();
    });

    ob_start();
    return $response;
    
});
```

O valor `{"process" : true}` é enviado imediatamente para o navegador, porém você perceberá que o navegador não vai ficar mais carregando.

Temos uns pontos importante que precisam ser entendidos aqui:

- Você precisa de executar o `ob_start`, ele inicia a captura do buffer de saída;
- Você precisa do `flush` e `ob_end_flush`  para descarregar o buffer para a saída. Eu fiz o teste sem a função `flush`, deixando apenas `ob_end_flush`, e funcionou perfeitamente.
- Você precisará do `ob_get_length`. No meu caso eu usei `mb_strlen($response->getContent())` por se tratar da classe específica do Framework que eu usei, mas no caso do PHP puro, você pode usar `ob_get_length` para obter o tamanho atual. Este parece ser um ponto importante, pois o navegador parece ler o tamanho do conteúdo recebido e o  tamanho enviado em `Content-Length` para decidir se vai fechar a conexão com o servidor.
- Coloquei o `ignore_user_abort(true)` por precausão, para dizer para o PHP não parar a execução do script após o fechamento da conexão. Nos meus testes com Laravel não fez diferença.

Eu coloquei o `sleep(3)` também, apenas para garantir que o teste iria funcionar corretamente, já que essa função atrasaria a requisição em 3 segundos. Com o código acima, o atraso ocorre na execução no servidor, porém não afetará o navegador, visto que o browser já fechou a conexão;

## FAST CGI

No FastCGI, parece que para resolver esse problema, basta você chamar a sua "tarefa" após a chamada da função `fastcgi_finish_request`:

```
 fastcgi_finish_request();
 minha_tarefa_demorada();
```

Comment: Todo este código está no arquivo de rotas (web.php)?